# How to pass an argument to a function when using ParameterExpression together with org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I am using org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification together with JpaSpecificationExecutor to easily create queries with conditions in Java but now I need to call a MySQL DB function that returns an integer value.

The problem is that it is unclear how to pass an argument for this function as I am not using TypedQuery:

```
// cb here is CriteriaBuilder
ParameterExpression param = cb.parameter(String.class);

Predicate predicate = cb.greaterThan(cb.function("A_FUNCTION", 
      Integer.class, param), 0);

Specification spec = cb.and(predicate);

// query is executed like this

return (int) repositoryThatExtendsJpaSpecificationExecutor.count(test);
```

And the example from [here](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-call-custom-function-criteriaquery/) is not helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you really need is a literal which you can create using [`CriteriaBuilder.literal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#literal-T-). A full example would look like

```
// cb here is CriteriaBuilder
Expression param = cb.literal("Stephen Hawking");

Predicate predicate = cb.greaterThan(cb.function("A_FUNCTION", 
      Integer.class, param), 0);

Specification spec = cb.and(predicate);
```

If the value doesn't come from your application you can use (m)any of the [functions returning an `Expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/class-use/Expression.html).